# JTextArea in vi mode

Tags: java, textarea, vi

Is there a free and open source extension of JTextArea that would support "vi mode"?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can find useful info here:  http://jvi.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no. This is such an obscure request, I think you'd have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I can't be *sure* that such a component does not exist, but I'd be truly astonished if it does. There is a [vi plugin for Eclipse](http://www.satokar.com/viplugin/), which presumably includes a Java implementation of the vi keybindings. However, that plugin is commercial, so you can't legitimately reuse that source code. As a matter of curiosity, what exactly do you want this for?